# How to replace character 'a' with 'b' and 'b' with 'a' in a string?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose I have the following string.

> blaah blaah blaah blaah

the resulting string should be:

> albbh albbh albbh albbh

Is there any built in method in JavaScript to find and replace a character like this in a string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
var str = "blaah blaah blaah blaah";
str = str.replace(/a|b/g, v => {
       if(v=="a"){
         return "b"
       }else{
         return "a"
       }
    });
    
console.log(str);
```

You can find more details about how this works [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)

The basic idea is that the function is invoked for each match and its return value will be the replacement string.

Comment: Or even `str = str.replace(/a|b/g, v => v == "a" ? "b" : "a");`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. @T.J.Crowder I didn't really understand the answer or even the question that you marked as duplicate. I like to keep things simple when asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can group either `a` or `b` and use the callback of replace to see if you're replacing an `a` or a `b`:

```
str = str.replace(/(a)|b/g, function(match, a) {
  return a? "b": "a";
});
```

```js
var str = "blaah blaah blaah blaah";

var newStr = str.replace(/(a)|b/g, (_, a) => a? "b": "a");

console.log(str, "becomes", newStr);
```